# WCF Client not consuming user-defined datatype from Web Service (SCVTrace included)

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, rest, soap

As requested - here is the trace i got from SVCTraceViewer.exe

`<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>524340</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-11-26T01:35:30.8037467Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{6a4de494-31a3-49ab-935f-419911742e44}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="13564" ThreadID="13" /><Channel /><Computer>CONNOR-PC</Computer></System>
    <ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
    <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.ServiceOperationExceptionOnReply.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
    <Description>Replying to an operation threw a exception.</Description><AppDomain>caf40de1-1-130299029702291231</AppDomain>
    <Source>System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime/11419366</Source><Exception>
    <ExceptionType>System.ObjectDisposedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
    <Message>The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.</Message>
    <StackTrace>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.get_Count()
       at WriteArrayOfProjectToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteUserToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteArrayOfUserToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.get_Count()
       at WriteArrayOfProjectToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteUserToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at WriteArrayOfUserToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>`

Recieving the following CommunicationException error when returning an auto generated entity class from my web service to the client

The User class is autogenerated when i import the database model, but it will not pass through the web service to the client when i call the following method.

```
  using (UserService1Client db = new UserService1Client()) {

             User[] newarray = db.userSearch(this.Model.Forename, 
                   this.Model.Surname, 
                   this.Model.Certifications, this.Model.UserTypes);
         kTrace); 
            }
```

Here's my stack trace..

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
There was a communication problem. The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at SimpleMvvmWpf1.Local_DatabaseServiceCS4.IUserService1.userSearch(String Forename, String Surname, String Certifications, String UserTypes)
   at SimpleMvvmWpf1.Local_DatabaseServiceCS4.UserService1Client.userSearch(String Forename, String Surname, String Certifications, String UserTypes) in i:\TRUNK\SimpleMvvmWpf1\SimpleMvvmWpf1\Service References\Local_DatabaseServiceCS4\Reference.cs:line 1613
   at SimpleMvvmWpf1.SearchViewModel.SubmitSearch() in i:\TRUNK\SimpleMvvmWpf1\SimpleMvvmWpf1\ViewModels\SearchViewModel.cs:line 51
```

And my methods..

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "GetUsers", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
List<User> GetUsers();


       public List<UserProfile> GetUsers()
    {
        using (cs4_databaseEntities entities = new cs4_databaseEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var queryResult = from i in entities.Users select i;
                List<User> uList= queryResult.ToList();
                return uList; 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return new List<UserProfile>();
            }
        }
    }
```

The User Class has the [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)] and the variables have the  [DataMemberAttribute()] however i'm still not getting anything through, i've also played about with the binding configuration setting `closeTimeout="00:40:00" openTimeout="00:40:00" receiveTimeout="00:40:00" sendTimeout="00:40:00"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"`

Any help would be great, this is rattLing my brain!!

Comment: IS this working with the `test client`?

Comment: Try turning on WCF tracing to get the actual exception being thrown on the server side. It will definietly give some more valuable information.

Comment: not working in the test client! i've traced the error and added it above! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using so called [*Lazy Loading*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) which in short means that data will be actually read only on demand. This will happen during response serialization (as it is shown in the stack trace), a long after your `DbContext` (`cs4_databaseEntities` in this case) is disposed - because it lives only within `using` block. The simplest solution is to disable lazy loading:

```
yourContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Refer for example [this good article](http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/more-with-the-entity-framework-v6-rc1/12423/#.UpQGncT3H7A) about this topic.